# How do I provide the specific details for this ambiguous method call?

Tags: c#, lambda

```
Map(x => x.Country).Convert(args => "USA"); //ambiguous
Map(x => x.Enabled).Convert(args => args.Row.GetField("PrimaryRecord") == "P"); //not ambiguous
```

Problem: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'MemberMap<TClass, TMember>.Convert(ConvertFromString)' and 'MemberMap<TClass, TMember>.Convert(ConvertToString)' [CNet.CTrack.Core]csharp(CS0121)

MemberMap<ZipPostalCodeImport, string> MemberMap<ZipPostalCodeImport, string>.Convert(ConvertFromString convertFromStringFunction) (+ 1 overload)

I'd like the first one "ConvertFromString". How do I specify?

[image: vs code screenshot]

SOLVED

I derived this from the comments:

```
Map(x => x.Country).Convert((ConvertFromString<string>) (args => "USA"));
```

The accepted answer:

```
Map(x => x.Country).Convert(convertFromStringFunction: args => "USA");
```

Both work.

Comment: Provide the types to the generic call. `Map<ZipSomethingICannotRead, string>(x => x.Country).Convert(args => “USA”)`

Comment: I've added the hard-to-read stuff. I haven't gotten it working yet.

Comment: I think the ambiguity is the Convert(), not Map()

Comment: Cast the function to pass to `Convert` as `ConvertFromString`.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, and that's what brought me here. I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepending the parameter name can also resolve the ambiguity if the parameter names differ:

```
Map(x => x.Country).Convert(convertFromStringFunction: args => "USA");
```